# Sort columns by column sums, identical columns adjacent

Tags: r, sorting, sum, col

I have a dataset consisting of dichotomous values. It's a very large dataset, but here's an example:

```
var1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
var2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
var3 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
var4 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
var5 <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
dat <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)
dat <- as.matrix(dat)
```

I'm trying to incorporate two commands into one. First, I want to cluster the columns such that identical columns are lumped together. Second, I want the columns to be ordered by column sums. I can do one or the other, but not both.

So, the output should look like this:

```
var2 var1 var5 var3 var4
   1    1    1    0    0
   1    0    1    0    0
   1    1    0    1    1
   1    1    0    1    1
   1    0    0    0    0
```

The highest column sums need not be located on the left.

I tried using this command:

```
 csums <- dat[,order(colSums(dat,na.rm=TRUE))]
```

But the columns do not cluster by similarity. Perhaps there's a way to cluster based on similarity, conditioned on column sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a bit of a strange solution. You can secondarily order by a collapsed string representation of the columns, which will serve as a tiebreaker for column sets that have equal `colSums()`. This will ensure that identical columns are clustered together, as they will lexicographically sort next to each other.

```
dat[,order(decreasing=T,colSums(dat,na.rm=T),apply(dat,2L,paste,collapse=''))];
##      var2 var1 var5 var3 var4
## [1,]    1    1    1    0    0
## [2,]    1    0    1    0    0
## [3,]    1    1    0    1    1
## [4,]    1    1    0    1    1
## [5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked perfectly. Why do you have "2L", rather than just "2" in the apply settings? Also, what function does paste and collapse perform?

Comment: It sounds like collapse is working as a secondary sorting procedure. What exactly does collapse = ' ' mean?

Comment: @jj987246 Take a look at the [`apply()` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html). The variadic `...` arguments are passed to `FUN()`, which in my solution means the `collapse=''` argument will be passed to `paste()`. Turning to the [`paste()` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html), we see that it takes a `collapse` parameter which, if specified, is used to collapse all elements of the final vector into a single element using the `collapse` string as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clustering (unsupervised structure discovery) problem, but simply a sorting problem with a non-trivial sorting logic.

Depending on what your tools offer, you can

1. sort lexicographically, then stable-sort by sum
2. sort by sum if different, sort lexicographically if same sum